# appendChild method not working

Tags: javascript, dom

Actually, it seems to work in JSFiddle without much problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/3zjqwbgy/5/

However, when I try to run it locally using Notepad++, I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

What could be the reason for this?  How can I make it work locally?

Comment: where is your script in html code?

Comment: Oops...No error in console for provided fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the HTML available when you run the `appendChild` method.

That means you'll wrap everything into an `load` handler:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
   /* your actual code */
   ...
   showElmntProperty("myDeck", "cardName", "first");
});
```

It's working in JSFiddle because JSFiddle is doing that for you automagically (by default)–you can change it, though:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your code works on JSFiddle, the only thing I can think of off the top of my head is you've misplaced your `<script></script>` tags.  Try moving them down below the Table, so that they can be "seen" by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get a "Cannot read property "some property name" of null, it simply means that the object that you are calling the method on doesn't actually refer to the object you think it is - it's not pointing to any object at all.

Now, in your code, you didn't say where (exactly) you are getting the error, but take these two lines:

```
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById(id).appendChild(node);
```

If you are getting the error on the first line, then the `node` variable does not, in fact, refer to anything. If it's the second line you are getting the error on, then `document.getElementById(id)` isn't returning an actual object, in which case, you'd need to check to see that the `id` variable you are using there actually matches an `id` of an HTML element.

And, of course, knowing when your code runs is vital. It may be that:

```
   document.getElementById(id)
```

Is attempting to locate an element before that element has been parsed into the DOM.